# JBoss Fuse unable to install bundel with maven install

Tags: java, maven, esb

I created maven project in eclipse to expose rest web service to JBoss Fuse and make maven clean and install and the package created in maven local repository in this path:

```
C:\Users\mohamed.mostafa\.m2\repository\com\javainuse\apache-camel-jaxrs\0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

I want to install this package to jboss fuse with this command:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root>install mvn:com/javainuse/apache-camel-jaxrs/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Please help me ...

Give me unable to install bundle `com/javainuse/apache-camel-jaxrs/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`

Answer (score 1):

This should be configured in org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg configuration available in etc folder.

Syntax you are using to install is wrong. It should be like below.

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root>install mvn:<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>
```

Example:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root>install mvn:com.javainuse/apache-camel-jaxrs/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
```

Also, it matters from where you are tying to install If you using nexus you could use something like below.

```
org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.repositories = http://someurl.com/nexus/content/groups/public@snapshots
```

If you want to use local maven repo.

> Path to the local maven repository which is used to avoid downloading
>    artifacts when they already exist locally.
>    The value of this property will be extracted from the settings.xml file
>    above, or defaulted to:
>        System.getProperty( "user.home" ) + "/.m2/repository"

```
 org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.defaultLocalRepoAsRemote = true
 org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository= Path of Local maven Repo
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an [OSGi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi) bundle for [JBoss FUSE](https://www.redhat.com/en/technologies/jboss-middleware/fuse) by using Maven you should add the [`maven-bundle-plugin`](http://felix.apache.org/components/bundle-plugin) to your pom.xml, and set packaging type to `bundle`:

```
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
        <extensions>true</extensions>
        <version>2.3.7</version>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

To make your bundle available for JBoss FUSE, build and install the artifact into your local Maven repository:

```
mvn -DskipTests=true clean install
```

To install your OSGi bundle in JBoss FUSE by using [Apache ServiceMix](http://servicemix.apache.org) or [Apache Karaf](https://karaf.apache.org), you can run the following command from its shell:

```
JBossFuse:karaf@root> osgi:install -s mvn:<groupId>/<artifactId>/<version>
```

You'll see:

```
Bundle ID: //some identifier here
```

Parameter `-s` allows to start bundles automatically.

Also JBoss FUSE provides a web administration console available at:

```
http://localhost:8181/hawtio
```

Among other things, there you can manage your bundles.

Important note: as described in the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse/6.3/pdf/Developing_and_Deploying_Applications/Red_Hat_JBoss_Fuse-6.3-Developing_and_Deploying_Applications-en-US.pdf),

> If your local Maven repository is stored in a non-standard location,
>   you might need to customize the value of the
>   `org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.localRepository` property in the
>   `InstallDir/etc/org.ops4j.pax.url.mvn.cfg` file, before you can use
>   the `mvn:` scheme to access Maven artifacts.